# PCGen not allowing improved trip at level 1 monk

Tags: pathfinder-1e, monk, archetype, pcgen

I am trying to create a monk pc using PCGen version 6.08 however it is telling me I do not meet the requirements for Improved Trip. It says "MonkBonusFeatLVL at least 6".

I am taking the [Maneuver Master](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/monk/archetypes/paizo-monk-archetypes/maneuver-master/) archetype which says I should be able to take any improved combat maneuver as a bonus feat.

I have 13 int and my other feats are Combat Reflexes and Vicious stomp (I am human)

Is this a bug with PCGen or am i missing something that means I am not allowed to take this feat?

Comment: Welcome! You can take the [tour] as an introduction to the site and check the [help] if you need further guidance. Good luck and happy gaming!

Answer (score 3):

### You should be able to add it

In pcgen, when creating a character that has the Maneuver Master archetype, on the feat menu, the bottom left selection allows a special "Maneuver Master Bonus Feat" which has all the improved maneuver feats available:

[image: maneuver selection printscreen]

This allows you to add any improved maneuver feat as a monk bonus feat from level 1.

### Possible fix for 6.08

After testing with version 6.08 I confirmed that the option is unavailable in that version, while in version 6.07.08 that I have the options works. One way to try to fix it is to use the option from the previous working version.

I tested this myself and the option worked, however, I will stress that **messing with pcgen files may have unintended consequences so use this at your own risk**. What I did was go to the pcgen installation folder and find the following file:

```
\data\pathfinder\paizo\roleplaying_game\ultimate_combat\uc_abilities_class.lst
```

You should backup this file just in case something goes wrong. Then, open the file with a text editor and find line 946, which should start with:

```
Bonus Feat                                  KEY:Maneuver Master ~ Bonus Feat
```

Then replace the entire line with:

```
Bonus Feat          KEY:Maneuver Master ~ Bonus Feat        CATEGORY:Special Ability    TYPE:MonkClassFeatures.ArchetypeAbility.SpecialQuality          DEFINE:MonkBonusFeatLVL|0   DESC:In addition to normal monk bonus feats, a maneuver master may select any Improved combat maneuver feat (such as Improved Overrun) as a bonus feat. At 6th level and above, he may select any Greater combat maneuver feat (such as Greater Grapple) as a bonus feat. At 10th level and above, he may select any maneuver Strike feat (such as Tripping Strike) as a bonus feat.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    BONUS:ABILITYPOOL|Maneuver Master Bonus Feat|1+MAX((MonkBonusFeatLVL+2)/4,0)    BONUS:VAR|MonkBonusFeatLVL|MonkLVL  SOURCEPAGE:p.58
```

Upon restarting pcgen, the option to select a maneuver master feat should now be available. However, do note that the option is bugged (even in my version) since it grants 2 bonus feats instead of one. This is probably just a minor inconvencience, though, remember to pick only 1 of these bonus feats.

Comment: Strange, I do not have the Maneuver "Master Bonus Feat section", its just "Feat" and "Monk Bonus Feat". I double checked and I have definitely added the "Maneuver Master" archetype.

Comment: @user56937 I have edited the answer to include a possible fix for this simply by using my version of the bonus feat ability in the pcgen files